# Android-7.0: EditText wrong actionId in editor actionlistener

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-7.0-nougat

I have an edit text declared in xml like this with following properties and i have set  `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ui_row_create_poll_edit_text_txt_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ui_row_create_task_user_info"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="@integer/task_length"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_very_large"/>
```

In code I have added the Editor actionlistener like this.

```
 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEventevent{
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
        listener.onActionDone(option, etOption);
    }
```

In Api < 24 i get  `actionId` as `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT` and it works fine. but when I run my app on Android 7.0 I get `actionId` as `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED`

[image]

Can somebody point out why i am getting different actionId in Api-24.
If there are any changes in editText in Android-7.0 kindly point me to some links.
Thanks.

**Note:** My editText is placed in a listview

Comment: try adding `android:inputType="text"` to your `EditText`

Comment: @Logic: still same result

Comment: No changes in Android 7. Your code working fine with actionId as IME_ACTION_NEXT in my Nougat device. Are you using any custom keyboard?

Comment: @FebiMathew: My editText is placed inside a listview. might be that will be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with using 
`android:imeActionLabel`
Try remove it and leave default implementation