# Android 7.0 : editText in a listview does not show keyboard on requesting focus

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a `ListView` which contains `EditText`as items and also `EditText` in `ListView` header.

[image]

When I tap on any `EditText` it shows the keyboard and allows me to enter text. But if I press the back button, it hides the keyboard and then tap on the `EditText` which was previously focused, does not open the keyboard.

Here is my `EditText` declared in xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ui_row_create_poll_edit_text_txt_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ui_row_create_task_user_info"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLength="@integer/task_length"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large_plus_little"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_very_large" />
```

I have tried added `onFocusedchanged` listener and `onTouchListener` but it doesn't work.

I have also tried to add the `onClickListener` and added the following code to display keyboard forcefully but this does not work either.

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.
    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 inputMethodManager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(windowToken, 0);
```

It works fine on < `Android-7.0`, but causes problem in API 24.

Is there any specific changes in `Android 7.0` related to `EditText`? Or can somebody come up with some solution?

**Note:** I am facing this issue only on Android-7.0. On previous version it works fine. 
Also I have faced another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784856/android-7-0-edittext-wrong-actionid-in-editor-actionlistener) which is also only occurring on 7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Comment: @Anjali: there is no issue with focus. issue is that it does not open the keyboard. EditText has the focus and cursor is there but keyboard is not opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question to close this issue. I just received an update patch for Android 7.0 and now it is working fine. It seems like it was a bug in 7.0 which is resolved in security path 5th October 2016.